# how can copy node to variable and use visit to remove some item?

Tags: fancytree

i use this code

```
var mdata = node//.toDict(function (n) {delete n.key});

mdata.visit(function (n) {
    if(n.data.itemtype !=='folder')
        n.remove();
});
```

when i remove items from mdata that's remove from original node

how can i copy node without any dependencies???

when i use `toDict` but i can't use `visit` to process node items

i use `Object.assign({},node)` and other methods but i can't do this

i need copy a node and paste that to other branch but remove some items before paste it

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy and modify a node, use `toDict`:

```
var d = node.toDict(true, function(dict){
    delete dict.key;
    if( dict.data.foo ) {}      
    ...  
});
```

then add it to the new target, e.g.

```
targetNode.addChildren(d);
```

Comment: i need the key
i want cut the branch and past at other position